# Linking column with different tables

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I don't think it's possible but i'm asking to be sure. Let's say I have a table called wp_users and forum_users. In wp_users there's a username, email, and md5 hash column. Same thing goes with forum_users. Is there a way to syncronize the two so that way something like

```
INSERT INTO wp_users (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[email]');
```

would automatically do

```
INSERT INTO forum_users (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[email]');
```

Same with ALTER etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use transactions

```
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO wp_users (username, password, email)
 VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[email]');
 INSERT INTO forum_users (username, password, email)
 VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[email]'); 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: i'm saying within the database structure itself so that way you don't have to use that. I want to setup the existing database structure to update a forum and wordpress site database at the same time without modifying the core files.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize **MySQL TRIGGERS** to automate this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_wp_users
AFTER INSERT ON wp_users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO forum_users (username, password, email)
    VALUES (NEW.username, NEW.password, NEW.email);
END
```

You can do the same for UPDATE and other queries.

***EDITED 1:***

In case, both tables are required to be updated automatically, i.e. if a row is inserted in the table `wp_users`, it is automatically inserted in `forum_users` and vice versa, writing the second set of triggers to update wp_users table from forum_users will introduce **recursive loop**.

To circumvent this, we can use a status variable to check if secondary insert should happen or not.

**Trigger 1:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_wp_users
AFTER INSERT ON wp_users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF @__disable_trigger_users = 1 THEN
        SET @__disable_trigger_users = NULL;
    ELSE
        SET @__disable_trigger_users = 1;
        INSERT INTO forum_users (username, password, email)
        VALUES (NEW.username, NEW.password, NEW.email);
    END IF;
END
```

**Trigger 2:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_forum_users
AFTER INSERT ON forum_users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF @__disable_trigger_users = 1 THEN
        SET @__disable_trigger_users = NULL;
    ELSE
        SET @__disable_trigger_users = 1;
        INSERT INTO wp_users (username, password, email)
        VALUES (NEW.username, NEW.password, NEW.email);
    END IF;
END
```

***EDITED 2***

You can also achieve the same using ***MySQL Store Procedure***.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_insert_user 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_insert_user
(
    IN  p_username   VARCHAR(15),
    IN  p_password   VARCHAR(15),
    IN  p_email      VARCHAR(15)  
)

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO wp_users (username, password, email)
    VALUES (p_username, p_password, p_email);

    INSERT INTO forum_users (username, password, email)
    VALUES (p_username, p_password, p_email);

END
GO

CALL proc_insert_user('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[email]')
GO
```

Comment: So to completely sync them I could do that and just change the values so that way you can update the wp database via the forums?

Comment: Right. You can write similar triggers for updating `wp_users` table from `forum_users` table. Need to check whether that will create some kind of loop/deadlock...

Comment: I've added a solution to the above loop problem.

Comment: I've edited the post to include an alternate solution using Store Procedures. Hoping it helps.